# Facebook Like Button - Show Faces Required in order to Show Stream

Tags: html, facebook-like

I'm trying to enter in a Facebook like button on my church's website mainly because I want the facebook stream to show up (which is basically just all the activity that has been posted by my page).

In the plugin setup (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), I am having to select "Show Faces" in order to "Show Stream".  If I deselect "Show Faces", my stream won't show, even though the check box for "Show Stream" is still selected.

I don't want the faces to show up, but I do want the stream.  Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug, you can track it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/186059584887628

---

**Update:** This should be fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

To set this up:

Un-check show faces.

Set the height of the app to 300 (or higher if you want to see a larger stream).

Press Get Code.

Done.